# iOS finds nil value when variable is instantiated with a value

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app with this code:

ViewController:

```
var viewModel : LoginViewModel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (self.viewModel.password_from_signup != "") {
```

ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel: NSObject {
    ....
    var password_from_signup: String = ""
```

And the app fails at the if statement in the viewController giving this error code:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How could it find a nil when I instantiate the String as ""?

Comment: Who is instantiating your `viewModel`?

Comment: Until you figure out optionals, don't use the force-unwrap or implicit unwrap  `!` operator. When you make a variable an implicitly unwrapped optional you create code that will crash when you try to read a value from that variable, even though the code that reads the value does not look like it is unwrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never instantiate a LoginViewModel based on the code you've give. You problem is not actually that password_from_signup is nil, but your viewModel is nil.

Comment: this is the answer thanks. I just added `self.viewModel = LoginViewModel()` and it worked.

Comment: @Rorschach - Or, more concisely, you can instantiate it right where you declared it, e.g. `let viewModel = LoginViewModel()`.

Comment: So then you should accept the answer to show that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You have not instantiated your `viewModel`. Try this:

```
var viewModel : LoginViewModel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    if (self.viewModel.password_from_signup != "") {
```